# Find a poset with infinitely many infinite chains and infinitely many infinite antichains.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I need to find some poset with infinitely many infinite chains and infinitely many infinite antichains.
I guess it can be something with real numbers or prime numbers.
But I can't find any relation like this between them.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Find a suitable partial order on $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$. I’ve left an additional hint in the spoiler-protected block below.

> Arrange it so that the chains are the sets $\{n\}\times\Bbb Z$ for $n\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: This is an answer that would come out of what is discouragingly called the "just do it" approach. Since the question doesn't require that any of the chains play nicely together with each other, why not just put them side by side? (And then, as if by magic, it turns out to satisfy the infinitely-many-antichains condition too.)

Comment: @Patrick: Or as I tend to think of it, ‘Do the simplest reasonable thing, and for a wonder it actually works!’

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Consider $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, partially ordered by inclusion